# Access Asp.net Page in Globally any where any time without error found

Tags: c#

I have asp.net page But now i am access using my office network(192.0.0.145/Mypageasp.aspx)
.But when i access From home It will show the error.How can access Asp.net page Globally what i should do ? Can You Provide Some example Could you help me Please

Answer (score 0):

`192.0.0.145` sames to be an Intranet ip, can  not use out side your office network.

Comment: then how to to do How to access Asp.net outside the office